# Removing dynamically Objects from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Via a `JSpinner` I want to add and remove object "porta" from a`JPanel`, it works fine for adding and when I remove only one object if I try to remove two or more objects it doesn't work properly. This is the code I think the issue is related to the last element of the `vector` on which I add the object "porta":

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PreparaGara extends JFrame {

public JSpinner spinner;
private JPanel panel_1,panel_2;
private int spin;
private int NPorta = 1;
private PortaP scorriPorta,porta;
final Vector<PortaP> vp = new Vector<PortaP>();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PreparaGara() {

    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 3, 3));


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

    JMenu mnGara = new JMenu("Gara");
    mnGara.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 30));
    menuBar.add(mnGara);

    panel_1 = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

    final JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));


    JMenuItem mntmPorte = new JMenuItem("Porte");
    mntmPorte.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    mntmPorte.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
            lbl.setText("Numero Porte : ");
            panel_1.add(lbl);


            SpinnerNumberModel sm =new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,30,1);
            final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
            panel_1.add(spinner);       
            spinner.getFocusListeners();
            spin=0;
            panel_1.revalidate();

            spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                    int ora=(int) spinner.getValue();

                    if(spin<ora && spin<30){

                        porta = new PortaP(NPorta);
                        panel_2.add(porta);
                        NPorta++;
                        vp.add(porta);
                        panel_2.revalidate();


                    }else{
                        //int i = vp.size();
                        panel_2.remove(vp.lastElement());
                        //panel_2.remove(porta);
                        vp.lastElement().remove(porta);                         
                        NPorta=NPorta-1;
                        //System.out.println(i);
                        panel_2.revalidate();
                        panel_2.repaint();
                    }

                spin=ora;
                }});
        }
    });
    mnGara.add(mntmPorte);

    JMenuItem mntmGiudici = new JMenuItem("Giudici");
    mntmGiudici.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    mnGara.add(mntmGiudici);

    JMenu mnDbase = new JMenu("Dbase");
    mnDbase.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 30));
    menuBar.add(mnDbase);

    JMenuItem mntmResetPenalit = new JMenuItem("Reset Penalit\u00E0");
    mnDbase.add(mntmResetPenalit);

    JMenuItem mntmResetPorte = new JMenuItem("Reset Porte");
    mnDbase.add(mntmResetPorte);

    JMenuItem mntmRestGiudici = new JMenuItem("Reset Giudici");
    mntmRestGiudici.setActionCommand("Reset Giudici");
    mnDbase.add(mntmRestGiudici);

    JMenu mnReturn = new JMenu("Return");
    mnReturn.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 30));
    menuBar.add(mnReturn);

    JMenuItem mntmChiudiMenu = new JMenuItem("Chiudi Menu");
    mnReturn.add(mntmChiudiMenu);






    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
  }

 }
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

I've done this.  First, I recommend that the portion of your panel that you intend to change should be a separate sub-panel.  And when an update occurs, call initialize() on that sub-panel with data indicating what it should contain.  You are thus essentially rebuilding the panel every time it changes.  Just make sure you don't have anything holding onto the old components (listeners and such), or else you will have memory leaks.

Someone else may have a better solution, but that is the cleanest I have found that works in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've discovered what was the issue, it was on the Vector

```
                    }else{

                        panel_2.remove(vp.lastElement());
                        // this is the correct instruction:
                        vp.remove(vp.lastElement());

                        NPorta=NPorta-1;
```

Instead of the wrong one:

```
                      vp.lastElement().remove(porta);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call repaint on every single change you make. This would insure that the changes are applied. You can try to create an additional Thread with LOW_PRIORITY which works simultaneously to the GUI's one and calls repaint() and validate() methods to your main frame.

```
Thread repainter = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) { // I recommend setting a condition for your panel being open/visible
        frame.repaint();
        frame.validate();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
});

repainter.setName("Panel repaint");
repainter.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
repainter.start();
```

Comment: There is no reason to do this.

Comment: I have had a similar issue. I was adding and removing elements. Sometimes it was working fine, but sometimes nothing happens. I've searched for the problem and found out this one as possible  solution and it worked for me.